# Hibernate cant see the created table in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

I am new to using Hibernate and HSQLDB .i have created a table and it is being displayed in the eclipse console as

```
    create table Employee (empId integer not null, empname varchar(255), primary key (empId))
    14:15:57,205 DEBUG SchemaExport:377 - create table Employee (empId integer not null, empname                       varchar(255), primary key (empId))
    14:15:57,206  INFO SchemaExport:268 - schema export complete
    14:15:57,209  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:170 - cleaning up connection pool:   jdbc:hsqldb:C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\hsqldb-2.2.6
```

However when i try to see the table in HSQLDB i am getting an error saying user lacks previlige or object not found:Employee

For connecting to HSQLDB I have given the url jdbc:hsqldb:C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\hsqldb-2.2.6

i am able too ping to the DB from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This method of access is not suitable for concurrent access from the program and IDE if they are not the same Java process.

For development, it is recommended to run the HSQLDB Server on your machine with a simple command. You then connect to the server using a URL such as `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test` from your program as well as the IDE. The server.properties file should include the lines that contain the real file URL to the database. See the Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html